# Trying to get an Oracle report to run to file

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I am on Oracle Reports 10g, and I have an RDF that I would like to schedule to run and create a PDF on my local folder. I thought this URL would work:

`http://mywebsite.com/reports/rwservlet?server=RptSvr_core2pweb99_asinst_1+userid=myuserid/password@database+report=/home/oracle/middleware/Oracle_FRHome1/forms/v10suite/GL573.rdf+destype=file+desname=c:\temp\GL573.pdf+desformat=pdf+P_unit=26014+P_TTLCOMP_YN=N`

My report is on an app server. If I changed the `DESTYPE` from `FILE` to `CACHE` and removed the `DESNAME` in the URL above, it would create a report in the browser.

Please advise, what am I missing?

OR, is there some way to create a report executable that I can run from my Windows 7 PC to create a PDF? (I was able to do this on Windows XP with `RWRUN`.)

Answer (score 1):

Only problem is of using wrong concatenation operator `+` which should be `&`, instead, before parameter names as in the following string :

```
http://mywebsite.com/reports/rwservlet?
server=RptSvr_core2pweb99_asinst_1
&userid=myuserid/password@database
&report=/home/oracle/middleware/Oracle_FRHome1/forms/v10suite/GL573.rdf
&destype=file
&desname=c:\temp\GL573.pdf
&desformat=pdf
&P_unit=26014&P_TTLCOMP_YN=N
```

P.S. without spaces inside string as in your case.